# Is there any way to Start SSMS connected to registered server

Tags: command-line, ssms

Is there any way to start SQL Server Management Studio to connect to a registered server?

I have managed to get it to start from the command line connecting to the desired DB with the use of the -S -d -U and -P parameters, but then the object explore is not connected.

Anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have created SSMSBoost add-in for SSMS and implemented "Preferred connections" feature. You can define the list of connections and choose to connect Object Explorer at start-up and/or to create new empty editor window. (This is one of many other features)